# Unable to implement the multi class transfer learning using VGG16 pre-trained model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to re-implement the transfer learning [from this link](https://github.com/pmarcelino/blog/blob/master/dogs_cats/dogs_cats.ipynb?fbclid=IwAR2CbZJZ37nvHTqoNoO_pQABkaE2Z1YlECmLL4QWk1KR2wRTm-TaCMf3q3E), I wanted to reimplement the code for the multiclass classification of my data.

My sample data is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/esirpr6q1lsdsms/ricetransfer1.zip?dl=0

I have tried the different suggestion available on the StackOverflow but it doesn't work.

```
# Extract features
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
train_size, validation_size, test_size = 148, 27, 31

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 16
train_dir = "ricetransfer1/train"
validation_dir = "ricetransfer1/validation"
test_dir="ricetransfer1/test"
#indices = np.random.choice(range(len(X_train)))

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
   #sample_count= X_train.ravel()

    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be 
    equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                        target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                        batch_size = batch_size,
                                        class_mode='binary')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, train_size)  # Agree with our small dataset size
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir, validation_size)
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, test_size)
```

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from the shape (16,4) into shape (16)

I wanted to use the transfer learning for the multiclass classification of image.

Comment: While trying with the image file of four classes, I also get an error, ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,4) into shape (32)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix `labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))` with `labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4))`, where four stands for four classes and now it will broadcast it without error.